# How to run WS in Win server 2003

Tags: c#

how can i run WS in Win server 2003 ?
i need to make virtual directory to put there my WS file
but it give me only make Web to put there my WS file

what can i do ?
i make many WS that work on Win XP and all work excelent, whay in Win 2003
it dosent ?

thank's for any help

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully follow the question, but it sounds like you're using IIS to host a web-service, and it isn't working. The usual cause is that you haven't configured the virtual directory in IIS; you must:

- ensure it is marked as an "application" (it should have a cog icon) - you do this on the properties dialog ("create application" or similar - a button on the right hand side, about 2-thirds down)
- ensure it is using ASP.NET 2.x (same dialog is IIS, ASP.NET tab)

Other than that, yuo'll have to describe the problem more.